# Implementing Multilingual web site using ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, localization

I am implementing an multilingual web site using ASP.Net. The languages are English,French and Arabic. Please note that Arabic's direction is RTL. What is the best way to implement the multilingual support. I am planning to use the .Net localization feature but the website texts are stored in DB. For the controls ( form controls) , I can used resx file. Do I need to build two different pages ( one for LTR and another for RTL )? Or can I have one ASPx file for all the three languages?

I would like to hear some best practices in implementing these kind of web applications.

Thanks in advance,
Abdel Olakara

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**First Issue of Multilingual:**
Simply make a basepage class that will inherited from Page class, put this method in basepage class and inherit basepage class in your every aspx.cs page to acheive globalization.

```
protected override void InitializeCulture() 
{ 
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("en-US"); //'en-US' these values are may be in your session and you  can use those
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");//'en-US' these values are may be in your session and you  can use those
    base.InitializeCulture(); 
}
```

**Second Issue of RTL and LTR:**
in your masterpage there is main div like..

```
<div runat="Server" id="divPageDirection">
</div>
```

you need to changed the direction and put this in your page load

```
divPageDirection.Attributes.Add("dir", "rtl");//rtl or ltr you will decide on which language is in your current session
```

please let me know if you any issue...

Comment: I would probably go for loading a different style sheet for Arabic. There might be various other layout things you need to fine tune.

Comment: I agree with this answer.. but my issue is.. where to i store the arabic, french and english texts? I mean, what is the best method?