# what are the sequence of steps or the source code for Localization using ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, localization, globalization

what has to be done for including Localization Concepts?
may i get the source code for each & every steps to be done?
is it necessary to include the resource files?
what has to be entered in the String & in the Value column while creating the Resource File?

Comment: Check this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793399/implementing-multilingual-web-site-using-asp-net/2793491#2793491

Answer (score 0):

**What has to be done for including Localization Concepts?**

The first step is to actually understand these concepts... You may want to read about it here:
[Effective Strategies for Localization in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5253614/247221)

**May I get the source code for each & every steps to be done?**

Oh dear... Such question is too broad and could be closed as not answerable. You would found plenty of examples and tutorials online. Just read them and ask **specific** questions about things you do not understand. But first, please try to search these questions using your favorite search provider (most of them were answered, some probably multiple times).

**Is it necessary to include the resource files?**

It is not necessary. However, for most of applications it is both easiest and fastest method. And simply the best method. And the only one which is really easy.

**What has to be entered in the String & in the Value column while creating the Resource File?**

In the first column you would need to put resource identifier - unique key that would identify your translatable string. Depending on Localization method you would choose, it could have different forms (for [implicit Localization](http://asp.net-tutorials.com/localization/implicit-and-explicit-localization/) it is best to keep it as control_identifier.property_name, where control_identifier is a string you put in ID attribute and property_name is name of the property you want to translate, i.e. lblName.Text). In the Value column you need to put your translatable string.